# I don't understand why, even though I want to display the result of A_inv multiplied by y from variable x1. Can you help me

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([(2, 3), (1, 2)])
y = np.array([(23, 14)])
print(A)
print(y)
A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A)
x1 = np.dot(A_inv, y)
print(x1)
```

> x1 = np.dot(A_inv, y)
> File "<**array_function** internals>", line 5, in dot
> ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

Comment: The dot product of two matrixes requires that the 2nd dimension of the first array equal the 1st dimension of the second array.

Comment: As a side note: If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using matmul or a @ b is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you trying to multiply a 2*2 array by a 1*2 array
to fix this add this:

```
y = np.array([(23, 14)]).reshape(2,1)
```

or just remove interior parenthesis from that:

```
y = np.array([23, 14])
```